# continuous drag or scaling in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

at present our project is using the leaflet, I take the map parameters to background program (`map.getZoom()` and `map.getbounds()`) , then load the returned picture(return from background program) by `imageoverlay`.
excuse me how to solve continuous drag or continuous scaling, only the implementation of calling a `daemon`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you dynamically load the base map (i.e. the image that is zoomable, draggable and that fills a big pane, not just a small portion that would have needed a single image overlay), you should probably rather do it through a [Canvas Tile Layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-canvas):

> Used to create Canvas-based tile layers where tiles get drawn on the browser side.

With this, you set up a `myCanvasTileLayer.drawTile` function that is called by Leaflet anytime the map needs more tiles (due to user panning / zooming). Please refer to Leaflet doc for the function arguments.

If you want to stick with your image overlay technique, you might want to listen to `drag` and `zoomend` [map events](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events) to re-trigger your function that loads a new image overlay.